# Can right click select everything under the cursor, instead of just one thing?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm moving some vertices of a mesh to be better aligned to a reference image:

[image]

The mesh has depth:

[image]

This involves a lot of box selection (or <kbd>C</kbd>):

[image]

Is there a way to configure Blender to make right click select everything under the cursor, to avoid having to do all of these box selections?

Comment: It's funny but I have the same problem right now (you came with your question just in time:)). I started to model a set of animals' base meshes and perpetual box selections with *B* or *C* drives me crazy. To speed up the selecting process I started to use **Ctrl+LMB** (hold Ctrl, then drag a mouse cursor). Using a *Mirror Modifier* is a big help here too. Though it would be great to have the functionality you described in your question.

Comment: Maybe it could be possible to remap Lasso select to tweak event (moving with RMB clicked), like [in example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7QGB.gif), I'm using RMB there. Note that default Tweak event for RMB will go away (not sure about Lasso select, maybe this could be created as additional mapping). I couldn't stop it from deselecting everything when occasionally selecting only one vertex so that's the subject for polishing (if possible)

Comment: If the depth is 2 vertices, you can double-click while holding Shift. Maybe it is somewhat easier to repeat. Otherwise I don't think there is easier way to do it :/ I am sure it could be done with an addon.

Answer (score 1):

On the buttons of the bottom bar is "**limit selection to visible**".

Turn this off and your selection will go through and selevt everything behind the box/lasso/etc selection area